# Count considering sum of 3 columns

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have 3 column (prod1 , prod2 , prod3 ) with TYPE : DOUBLE

```
id |  prod1  |  prod2  | prod3  |
1  |   1.3   |   2.6   |  2.8   |
2  |   0.8   |   3.4   |   0    |
3  |    0    |    0    |  1.3   |
4  |    0    |    0    |   0    |
```

What I want is `COUNT()` of 3 columns

```
SELECT count(prod1,prod2,prod3) AS allc 
  FROM `testprd` 
 WHERE id =3
```

I know above code is wrong

SHOULD GIVE RESULT

```
allc
-------
 1
```

As `prod1` and `prod2` have `0` values

Similarly when `id = 4`  count should be `0` as all column for resp `id` have zero value ,but when `id = 1` then count should be `3`

Hence I taught count for each id columns and then sum of all , will result me solution but  am not able to reach it.

BELOW IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED

```
SELECT count(prod1) AS a, 
       count(prod2) AS b, 
       count(prod3) AS c 
  FROM `testprd` 
 WHERE id =3
```

Result:

```
a |  b   |  c 
-------------
1    1     1
```

But should be:

```
a |  b   |  c 
-------------
0    0     1
```

So `sum(a+b+c) = 1`

Hence count for `id = 3` is `1`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the result you want to have with

```
SELECT  
    (prod1 !=0 ) + (prod2 != 0) + (prod3 != 0) AS allc 
FROM `testprd` 
WHERE id = 3
```

The aggregate function [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) counts rows in a table or not null rows in a certain column, but not the values that are not equal zero in a set of columns.

> COUNT(expr)
>
> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows
>   retrieved by a SELECT statement. The result is a BIGINT value.
>
> COUNT() returns 0 if there were no matching rows.

Comment: thanks this is what i needed . can you guide me :

"SELECT (prod1 !=0 ) + (prod2 != 0) + (prod3 != 0) AS allc " why its taking 0,0,1 why not 0,0,1.3   for id = 3 

but its working i am bit confuse with above  :)

Comment: can you guide me differnce between : " SELECT (prod1 !=0 ) "  and " SELECT prod1 " i know  " SELECT prod1 " this will return its value ... but why " SELECT (prod1 !=0 ) " return 1

Comment: This is a boolean expression. It will return 1 for true and 0 for false.

Comment: Ah, MySQL! Adding boolean values, what a nice system to work with ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT id, if(prod1+prod2+prod3>0,1,0) from testprd;
```

For all columns separated it should be:

```
SELECT id, if(prod1>0,1,0), if(prod2>0,1,0), if(prod3>0,1,0) from testprd;
```

Comment: hey can you guide me why you have used this " (prod1 > 0,1,0) " and what it does

Comment: The IF function simply takes three paramters, the first one should be a boolean type (or an expression that evalutes to boolean). If that parameter is true, then the function returns the second parameter else it returns the third. Simply IF(something is true, return this, else return that);

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple query like this

```
SELECT
    IF(prod1 > 0,1,0)+IF(prod2 > 0,1,0)+IF(prod3 > 0,1,0) as Total
FROM test
WHERE id = 3;
```

#### SQL Fiddle Demo

OUTPUT

```
| TOTAL |
|-------|
|     1 |
```

Comment: hey can you guide me why you have used this " (prod1 > 0,1,0) " and what it does

Comment: sure. i am telling if prod1 is greater then 0 then take 1 else take 0. This way it will take `0+0+1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if that product is different from zero then sum all counts like:

```
 SELECT if(prod1!=0,1,0) +  
        if(prod1!=0,1,0) +, 
        if(prod1!=0,1,0) AS ct 
   FROM `testprd` 
  WHERE id =3
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
       SELECT 
          count(*) AS allc FROM `testprd` 
       WHERE 
          id =3 AND 
          0 < ANY (prod1, prod2, prod3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` counts the rows slected by your `SELECT` statement, it does not sum up the column values.

```
SELECT prod1 + prod2 + prod3 AS mySum 
    FROM `testprd` 
    WHERE id =3;
```

See the MySQL doc concerning [Arithmetic Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html) and [COUNT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)